# Calling readline() makes errno 2 in C. Does anyone know about this?

Tags: c, gcc, readline

While testing my code, I have found out readline makes errno 2. This is ENOENT which means No such file or directory.
Does anyone know why??

```
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
        char *a = readline("shell$");
        printf("%d\n", errno);
        while (a)
        {
                printf("%s\n", a);
                readline("shell$");
        }
}
```

Do I have to set errno to 2 after readline? or Is it an error?

its in Macos

compiled with this comm -> gcc -lreadline main.c

Since I am using the Mac which is provided from a kind of institution, I don't have super privileges. Maybe could it cause the error? permission thing?

Comment: What happens if you put `errno = 0;` before he first call to `readline`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I had done that before, the value was still 2 :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a function does not return error value (or otherwise indicate there was an error), then, generally speaking, valuenof `errno` is not set or reset by it.

So probably some operation done by `readline` had an error, but it was recoverable and `readline` succeeded and did not touch `errno` itself.

So, before checking `errno`, you have to check if the function failed (or otherwise is documented to set `errno` in some specific way), usually by checking the return value.